# assign the outputs in a loop to a single list or array

Tags: python, loops

I am still finding my way in Python so this question may be very basic:
I am trying to generate some cosine waves in python and then do a Fourier transform on them. I am wrote the following code:

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
x = linspace(-5,5,100)
t = linspace(0,2000,2001)
w1=cos(2*pi*3*t/2001)
w2=cos(2*pi*10*t/2001)
fourier=0
long(fourier)

Trace = w1+w2
for i in range(1,125,1):
    fourier[i] = sum(cos(2*pi*i*t/2001)*Trace)

print fourier
f=linspace(1,125,125)
plot(f,fourier)
show()
```

so instead of calculating the values frequency by frequency I want to make a loop that takes each frequency from 1 to 125 and store the outputs in one list so that I can plot them.

Python does not like this and gives a message saying:

```
fourier[i] = sum(cos(2*pi*i*t/2001)*Trace)
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

Any idea why?

Comment: you need  `range(1,126)` to match the the dimensions of  `f` for plotting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be you want:

```
fourier = []
```

you decleared it as integer, you need to declear as list.

your fourior type is integer and you need to make it as list so it can support index assignment

also remove long(fourier) from your code

```
for i in range(1,126):
    fourier[i] = sum(cos(2*pi*i*t/2001)*Trace)
```

this will give you index out of index error

correct would be:

```
for i in range(1,126):    # you dont need last option as 1, because range step is one by default
    fourier.append(sum(cos(2*pi*i*t/2001)*Trace))
 OR
    fourier.insert(i,sum(cos(2*pi*i*t/2001)*Trace))
```

its better to use list comprehension and you need to set range to 126 to match the dimensions of `f` for plotting:

```
fourier = [sum(cos(2*pi*i*t/2001)*Trace) for i in range(1,126)]
```

Comment: both of these answers will still produce an error when trying to access `fourier[i]` on a list with No items

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes mentioned it will give list out of index error :)

Comment: better to just use a list comp and the range needs to be 126

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Happy Christmas :)

Comment: happy christmas to you too :)

Answer (score 1):

You need an array initialization:    `fourier=[]`

```
for i in range(1,125):
  fourier.append(sum(cos(2*pi*i*t/2001)*Trace))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to build up a list of objects/numbers.

The simplest is a for loop:

```
# create a list of squared numbers
squares = []
for item in range(10):
    squares.append(item*item)
```

This can also be done using a "list comprehension":

```
# produces identical list to the above for loop
squares = [(item * item) for item in range(10)]
```

Finally, you are using numpy, this allows to do "vector" operations on arrays. The following is a simple example of the above square code.

eg.

```
numbers = numpy.array(range(10))
# or you could write -- numbers = numpy.arange(10)
squares = numbers * numbers
```

However, you can also do very complicated vector arithmetic as well. This allows you to create your Fourier transform very easily.

```
indices = array(range(125), ndmin=2).T
arr_fourier =  (cos(2*pi*indices*t/2001)*Trace).sum(axis=1)
```

Note that `i` has been replaced by `indices`. When multiplying the `indices` by `t` we create a transpose of the `indices` array so that we end up creating a 2d array as a result. At the end of the process you sum over the one of the axes (in this case 1) to reduce the 2d array back down to a 1d array of length 125.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
x = linspace(-5,5,100)
t = linspace(0,2000,2001)
w1=cos(2*pi*3*t/2001)
w2=cos(2*pi*10*t/2001)
fourier=[]
Trace = w1+w2
    for i in range(1,126):
        fourier.append(sum(cos(2*pi*i*t/2001)*Trace))
print fourier
f=linspace(1,125,125)
plot(f,fourier)
show()
```